# UIView.animateWithDuration not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a messaging app. When the keyboard is shown, I want the UITextField to move up along with it, just as it does in the Messages app. However, my animation call is not working. It does not animate the textInputView as it should, but still calls the completion block after:

```
func keyboardWasShown(aNotification: NSNotification)
{
    var info = aNotification.userInfo! as Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>
    var kbSize = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.textInputView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.textInputView.frame.height - kbSize!.height


        println("Should move textInputView to: \(self.textInputView.frame.origin.y)") 

        }) { (bool) -> Void in


            println("Location of textInputView.frame.origin.y after animation: \(self.textInputView.frame.origin.y)")

    }
}
```

When I run this code, it prints:

Should move textInputView.frame.origin.y to: 297.0

Location of textInputView.frame.origin.y after animation: 521.0

Why is it not animating?

Comment: What is it doing? Staying in the same place? Moving without animation?

Comment: Why are you attempting to change frame in `completion` closure?

Comment: @akashivskyy is right, but changes to the frame probably won't work at all if you're using Auto Layout.

Comment: Sorry, here is a revision to my problem: When the keyboard is off the screen, and I tap the textfield, it pops up and the animation does not run, but oddly, when I enable the little suggestions bar above the keyboard (which also calls the keyboard was shown method), the animation runs.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very poorly written (and its unclear what you're asking) but I noticed a very common mistake. You're trying to set the frame's individual property instead of changing the whole frame.

Your method should look like this:

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue().size.height

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {

        var frame: CGRect = textInputView.frame
        frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame) - CGRectGetMaxY(textInputView.frame) - keyboardHeight

        textInputView.frame = frame // change the whole frame

    }, completion: nil)

}
```

Please consult some UIKit 101 tutorials for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the closure. If you notice your closure:

```
{ (bool) -> Void in


        println("Location of textInputView.frame.origin.y after animation: \(self.textInputView.frame.origin.y)")

}
```

is outside:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in

    self.textInputView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.textInputView.frame.height - kbSize!.height


    println("Should move textInputView to: \(self.textInputView.frame.origin.y)") 

    })
```

The Intellisense of Apple Xcode 6.1 is poor as far as the closures are concerned. Try manually writing the closure rather than clicking or pressing enter with the  intellisense suggestion.

Comment: isn't that just trailing closure syntax?

Comment: It should be, but wasn't working with me as well. worked well after this change. The closures going outside functions aren't being accepted. look at '(' ')' i.e. scope of the function.